# Codeigniter search query, I want to add another condition to my search

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my table:

Category:

```
{category_id , category }
```

Document:

```
{document_id, title, address, category}
```

My **controller**:

```
Class Search Extends CI_Contrller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
    }

}
```

My **model**:

```
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('name',$keyword);
        $query  =   $this->db->get('document');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

And this is my **view**:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('search/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
<input type="text" name = "keyword" />
<input type="submit" value = "Search" />
</form>
<table>
?>
foreach($results as $row){
<?php
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->title?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->category?></td>
    </tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
```

According to the controller and model shown above, I can only retrieve one keyword, which is my title of the document, but now I want to:

**Add to condition one if `title = $keyword` and `category=$keyword2`.**

Is it possible in this MVC or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it.

```
  Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
 {
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    }

  function search($keyword)
  {
    $this->db->where('name',$keyword);
    $this->db->where('category',$keyword2);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('document');
    return $query->result();
  }
```

}

Or you can also use condition.

```
 $this->db->like('name',$keyword);
 $this->db->like('category',$keyword2);
```

And define **$keyword2** in your controllers

Answer (score 1):

Simply use one extra like statement but for this you require one new argument $keyword2.pass that from controller to model.

```
$this->db->select('*'); 
 $this->db->from('document');
 $this->db->like('name', $keyword1);   
 $this->db->like('category', $keyword2);       
 return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: what are you exactly doing ? means put code here so that i can know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just add another method to your model where you are querieng for the keyword2 in the category field.
In your controller simply assign the return to another array item like 'results2'.
Hope that this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible in Codeigniter & you should have get it working by the above solutions posted.

No problem though.Try to follow this steps & let me know if you find any problem.

```
1) Add input text field named 'keyword2' to your view
2) Read 'keyword2' value in Controller like 'keyword' 
**$keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');**
```

Pass both keywords to model

```
3) $data['results'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword,$keyword2);
```

Your Search function in model should look like this :

```
function search($keyword,$keyword2)
{
    $this->db->like('name',$keyword);
    $this->db->like('name',$keyword2);
    $query  =   $this->db->get('document');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Best Regards,
Zeeshan.